# Typescript - iterating in order to parse/refine an Object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to parse an object to refine the unnecessary data - in this case I get an error at `rtn[key]`, and I have no understanding of why. Please read the tl;dr for some more context and thanks in advance;

```
type TValueCar = { make: { value: string }; model: { value: string } };
type TCarKey = keyof TValueCar;
type TCar = { make: { value: string }; model: { value: string } };

const parseCarValueObject = (valueObject: TValueCar): TCar => {
  const ObjectKeys = Object.keys(valueObject) as TCarKey[];

  const rtn = {} as TCar;
  ObjectKeys.forEach((key) => {
    rtn[key] = valueObject[key].value;
  });

  return rtn;
};
```

tl;dr
I am hoping to create a generic version of this function, and this is the first stage in my attempt. I realise that there is an easier way of solving this which doesn't would be very simple but wouldn't be helpful in my attempt to create the generic function. [Extract below]

```
const rtn = {
    make:valueObject.make.value,
    model:valueObject.model.value
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
rtn[key] = valueObject[key].value;
```

You are trying to assign the string of value from `valueObject` to the `type TCar` that expects an object of type `{ value: "something" }`, this is why you're getting this error.

try to simply remove the access to `value` in order to assign the whole object to your `rtn` variable.

```
const parseCarValueObject = (valueObject: TValueCar): TCar => {
  const ObjectKeys = Object.keys(valueObject) as TCarKey[];

  const rtn = {} as TCar;
  ObjectKeys.forEach((key) => {
    // It should works now
    rtn[key] = valueObject[key];
  });

  return rtn;
};
```

See the example on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgagQwDYFcIGEECcoF4oDeUAtggNYQBchUAbsmtQM7BYCWAdgOZQC%20A3CQD2AEwhJqReqipQW7bnz78AUKEixMWANIQQeKBRBCAZrEQytq9dBhaDRUhUl0Gs%20Zx4DhYiTWmMcqyeSgIqKgDGQhwsUGDYTBjYFmgA8gBGAFYQEcAGABQBEBnZudTwbloAlOX2uAB8hCpQUFExeSU5wLogTAaduQB0RkyFbgPAVVAIfXbYPQDaALqqLeEtbbFYwBwOvNOzVs1QEz1MgyZCWACiCBEAFvn5RlMNNC1Qxy3bHAtGSwYihM-noVsdeFVVMcsBBgCgsLsfqowpForEIslxlkug4nLICEVqAAiYAQFhE3gAGh84kkhKgJLJwAATBTeCp4lhEloUsVsbl8hisLyJlUgA)

Comment: Thanks, this has worked now. My error was actually just writing TCar incorrectly it should have been `type TCar = { make: string; model: string };` but either way you have cleared things up for me. Thanks @Yago Biermann